# MVC Navigate to different controller view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I'm having trouble navigating to a different controller view from another controller action.
e.g. return view("edit", "profile", profile);

I'm trying to navigate from the account controller to the edit view in the profile controller.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
RedirectToAction("Edit", "Profile", new {id = 1, otherParam = "foo"});
```

This won't render view of another controller - but it will navigate to action of another controller (which is supposed to render view you are looking for).

Comment: I also want the view to be rendered. But How?